# Error Code: 1114. The table is full

Tags: mysql

Here is what I tried so far:

1. innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
2. tmpdir to new path
3. max_heap_table_size=256M
4. tmp_table_size=256M
5. I check the C disk, which has over 100G remaining. My program and data are both located on this C disk.

My Specs:

1. MySQL Server 8.0.23 64bit
2. Windows 10

Query that works:

```
SELECT 
case_month,
res_state,
state_fips_code,
res_county,
county_fips_code,
age_group,
sex,
race,
ethnicity,
count(current_status) as current_status,
sum(case when hosp_yn = "Yes" then 1 else 0 end) as hosp_yn,
sum(case when icu_yn = "Yes" then 1 else 0 end) as icu_yn,
sum(case when death_yn = "Yes" then 1 else 0 end) as death_yn,
sum(case when underlying_conditions_yn = "Yes" then 1 else 0 end) as underlying_conditions_yn
-- sum(case when underlying_conditions_yn = "Yes" and death_yn = "Yes" then 1 else 0 end) underlying_conditions_death
FROM covid.covid_ifr
group by case_month,
res_state,
state_fips_code,
res_county,
county_fips_code,
age_group,
sex,
race
```

Problem Query:

```
SELECT 
case_month,
res_state,
state_fips_code,
res_county,
county_fips_code,
age_group,
sex,
race,
ethnicity,
count(current_status) as current_status,
sum(case when hosp_yn = "Yes" then 1 else 0 end) as hosp_yn,
sum(case when icu_yn = "Yes" then 1 else 0 end) as icu_yn,
sum(case when death_yn = "Yes" then 1 else 0 end) as death_yn,
sum(case when underlying_conditions_yn = "Yes" then 1 else 0 end) as underlying_conditions_yn,
sum(case when underlying_conditions_yn = "Yes" and death_yn = "Yes" then 1 else 0 end) underlying_conditions_death
FROM covid.covid_ifr
group by case_month,
res_state,
state_fips_code,
res_county,
county_fips_code,
age_group,
sex,
race
```

Table Structure:

```
create table covid_ifr (
case_month varchar(255),
res_state varchar(255),
state_fips_code varchar(255),
res_county varchar(255),
county_fips_code varchar(255),
age_group varchar(255),
sex varchar(255),
race varchar(255),
ethnicity varchar(255),
case_positive_specimen_interval varchar(255),
case_onset_interval varchar(255),
process varchar(255),
exposure_yn varchar(255),
current_status varchar(255),
symptom_status varchar(255),
hosp_yn varchar(255),
icu_yn varchar(255),
death_yn varchar(255),
underlying_conditions_yn varchar(255)
)
```

I have two queries that are nearly identical. The first one runs no problem and outputs a .csv slightly under 50MB and 535k rows. The problem query I added an extra field and this is where I encounter a problem. The table I am querying is about 4.5G. I have over 100G on my C Drive where MySQL is being run and located. My "Data" section is located in ProgramData file. I have spent roughly 8 hours on this issue and have read a lot of documentation. If this is somehow a space issue, please guide me on how I would check or fix this.

Comment: Is the tmp directory on a separate (smaller) disk partition?  Or is it in C:?  I understand that there is a variety of sexes now, on beyond must "M" and "F", But do you really need 255 characters?  Seriously, lower those "255s" to 'reasonable' values; it _may_ solve your problem.

Comment: The tmp directory is on C disk. I'm attempting to alter table but now I'm seeing another issue: ERROR 1206: The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size. I'm trying to update my innodb_buffer_pool_size to 500M now

Comment: I reran the problem query after pairing down the character limit of the table considerably and it's still not working. Any other suggestions?